# How does a delegate method know when to be called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, delegates

I'm just wondering how exactly does a delegate method know when to be called? For example in the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method is called when editing begins in the textfield (provided I implemented this method).

So how exactly does the code to detect when to call `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`? Does the system just check if `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` is already implemented and if it is it runs that method? Is there something under the hood that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly.

I can't vouch for how Apple's framework code is implemented under the hood, but an exceedingly common refrain is:

```
if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(someInstance:didDoSomethingWith:)]) {
    [[self delegate] someInstance:self didDoSomethingWith:foo];
}
```

This allows you to have optional delegate methods, which appears to be your question.

Comment: After the check, I would use 'performSelector' instead, so the compiler stays happy.

Comment: Considering that the delegate will be of type `id<UITextFieldDelegate>`, performSelector is not needed to keep the compiler happy.

Comment: @ranReloaded @CrimsonDiego is precisely correct on why you don't need `-performSelector:`.  In fact, `-performSelector:` is quite limited in what sorts of arguments can be passed to the method indicated by the selector, so it's often ill-suited for such purposes.

Comment: @ranReloaded Also, in exceptional circumstances, casting an object to conform to a protocol might be necessary to suppress compiler warnings, but this is quite rare in my experience.

Comment: Haven't checked this but, the compiler doesn't warn for potentially unimplemented @optional methods, as long as the delegate is declared to conform to the protocol?

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't 'detect when to call' a delegate method. The textField receives an event, and calls the method on it's delegate (which has the textFieldDidBeginEditing: method implemented).

In short, when you tap the textfield to start editing, the *textField* says 'oh, I'm editing now!' and internally calls `[self.delegate textFieldDidBeginEditing:self]`, where the delegate is the instance in which you've set to be the delegate (usually a UIViewController subclass)

Comment: Not exactly.  The OP is quite correct that code may need to know when to call a delegate method *if the delegate method is optional*. `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` is very much an optional method, so just calling it (as you suggest) would result in a run-time error/crash if `[self delegate]` is non-nil but doesn't implement that particular method.

Comment: In my opinion, he was asking how it knows *when* to call the method, rather than how it knows if a method is implemented, in which case my answer is correct regardless. I didn't add the `respondsToSelector` because he was asking a general question with an example that happens to be optional. Not all delegate protocols are optional, ergo my answer is still valid.

Comment: Well, I guess we have different interpretations (and only the OP could clarify).  I read "Does the system just check if textFieldDidBeginEditing is already implemented and if it is it runs that method?" as an indication of concern over checking implementation.

Comment: It says so right in the title - three times in fact, throughout the question as a whole. 'When does the delegate method know to be called' - not `How does it know if it can call the delegate method`.

Comment: I don't disagree that it says that; maybe I'm just reading too much into the question because I didn't want to believe it really was that simple (in which case your answer is of course spot on).