# Advertise and event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uiscrollview, uiimageview

So I have a `UIScrollView`  with  multiple `UIImageViews`
I had to generate my own class of  scroll view in order to tap into it's `touchesEnded`

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
//    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch  *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint   point = [touch locationInView:self];

    if ((int)(point.x / 100) < [[self items] count] ) {
        NSLog(@" ENDED  D    File Selected is   %@     %d   " , [[self items]  objectAtIndex:(int)(point.x / 100) ]   ,  (int)(point.x / 100)   );
    }
//    [[self nextResponder] touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

items is an `NSMutableArray`  within which I store the name of the file pointed to by each subview  so basically  `subview[0] ===  item[0]`  etc...

`subview[0]` is the image View and `item[0]` is the `fileName` of that image

My question is this  How can I now "advertise"  alert the original caller that file xyz  was selected ? As opposed to the `NSLog` line ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "original caller"?  `-touchesEnded:withEvent:` is called by the framework event handling subsystem.

What you might do (but don't! see below) is to add add some delegate methods of your own to the existing delegate (obviously there is already a `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol and corresponding `-[UIScrollView delegate]` property) and call out to the delegate method you defined in lieu of your `NSLog()`.  I discussed the refrain for doing this in a [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091975/how-does-a-delegate-method-know-when-to-be-called/11092095#11092095).

**However**, this is all moot because you are really approaching this backward and creating lots of unnecessary work for yourself.  I'll preface this by saying that there are certain classes for which subclassing ought to be a trigger that you need to reconsider your design. and `UIScrollView` is one such class.

You have already acknowledged that you have a collection of `UIImageView` objects.  You should let *them* handle interaction.  The general idea would be:

1) Send each instance something like `[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`.  This is the single most commonly overlooked mistake when working with interactive image views.

2) Add an appropriate concrete `UIGestureRecognizer` instance to each image view and implement the gesture recognizer callbacks.  Unless you absolutely must support ancient iOS releases, you should ***always*** try to use gesture recognizers in lieu of explicit touch handling.

3) In the gesture recognizer callbacks, add your logic code that takes an appropriate action based on the sending gesture recognizer's `-view`.  (You could, for example, examine the corresponding view's `-image` or `-frame` and use the information to decide which image was touched.)

Since the gesture recognizer callback will likely be in your view controller it will have a much easier time "talking" to the rest of your code.

Comment: original caller  => I guess the current ViewController.   Whatever called the scrollView

Comment: I think I found a solution using  NSNotififcationCenter   I have a postNotificationName in place of the NSLog line   and then in the ViewController's  viewDidLoad function I have an  addObserver  which seems to be working.     not sure if it is right ?

Comment: @BarryF No, please re-read what I wrote.  You are engaging in what is usually called "fighting the framework."  `NSNotificationCenter` is useful for having loose relationships between objects.  It is NOT intended for this use.  Please try the gesture recognizer approach.